# Spring doesn't inject beans to bean with @Scheduled method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

Im using Spring @Scheduled annotation for the first time. I've enabled scheduling in configuration, and schedule method works perfectly.

My problem is, that Spring doesn't inject required beans into my bean with @Scheduled annotated method. What I actually get is an LockService proxy object, which is useless in this case.

Is there any way to inject Spring beans into a bean with scheduled task?

I've tried with @Lazy annotation under @Autowired annotation, but result was the same. Getting bean from injected ApplicationContext has no result also.

Here is my bean with not injected dependencies:

```
@Component
    public class LockScheduler extends AbstractScheduler {

        private final LockService lockService; 

        @Autowired
        public LockScheduler(LockService lockService) {
            this.lockService = lockService;
        }

        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000)
        public void removeAbandonedLocks() {
            if (!isSchedulingEnabled()) {
                return;
            }

            LOG.info("Execute abandoned lock remove");
            lockService.removeAbandonedLocks();
        }

    }
```

I guess it is something with Aspects, that I cant reach ApplicationContext from bean with scheduled tasks.

UPDATE:

I've posted screen from debug mode. Instead of LockService object I get proxy with null reference to LockRepository, therefore breakpointed method execute has no effect. 
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that the `LockScheduler` bean is a proxy and that you don't want that? How do you think `@Scheduled` behavior is implemented? Why do you think the proxy is useless?

Comment: I do not think proxy is useless, but in this case I would like to obtain maintainable dependency, which actually do its job. Now lockService.removeAbandonedLocks(); method execution has no effect.

Comment: I'm very confused. Please provide a [mcve] and explain the behavior you expect and how it's different from the actual behavior.

Comment: I've updated my question with image from debu mode. Please look at this question again. I hope it is now more explanatory.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your problem is not in the `LockScheduler` at all, but rather in the `LockService`.  Somehow, your `LockService` is being initialized without its repository.  Are you sure that *that* component is correctly configured?

Comment: Yes, in other parts of my app it works perfectly well. It is being used in almost every controller, being injected with @Autowired annotation. The case that I describe with aopProxy happens first time, and I guess it is strongly couped with Scheduler mechanism.

Comment: Don't try to understand the proxy through the debugger. The repository is likely referenced somewhere else within those interceptors. Until you can come up with a [mcve], I have to believe this works correctly.